# angular 2: prevent user to click outside the modal dialog

Tags: css, angular, modal-dialog, angular-material2

I want to prevent from the user to click outside the modal dialog and he only can press on the button to exit from the dialog. how can I do that?

dialog.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogResultComponent);
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

}

dialog-result.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { FormGroup,FormControl,Validators,FormBuilder,  } from '@angular/forms';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-result',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result.component.html',
})

export class DialogResultComponent {


  form: FormGroup;
  name = new FormControl('',Validators.required);
  width = new FormControl('',Validators.required);
  height = new FormControl('',Validators.required);
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogResultComponent>,private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
      'name' :this.name,
      'width':   this.width,
      'height':  this.height,
    });
}

  saveData(){
    console.log(this.name.value);
    this.dialogRef.close({name:this.name.value,width:this.width.value,height:this.height.value});
  }
}
```

what I tried to do is:
**dialog-result.component.html**

```
       <div>
   <form [formGroup]="form">
     <h3>MineSweeperwix</h3>
      <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
                <p><mdl-textfield type="text" label="name" ([ngModel])="name" floating-label autofocus></mdl-textfield></p>
                <mdl-textfield type="number" formControlName="width"  label="width"   floating-label autofocus></mdl-textfield>
               <mdl-textfield type="number" formControlName="height" label="height" floating-label autofocus  error-msg="'Please provide a correct email!'"></mdl-textfield>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
        <button mdl-button (click)="saveData()" mdl-button-type="raised" mdl-colored="primary" mdl-ripple [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
        <button mdl-button (click)="dialogRef.close(dd)" mdl-button-type="raised" mdl-ripple>Cancel</button>
      </div>
   </form>
   </div>
```

dialog-result.component.cs

```
    div.modal-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100; /* less than your dialog but greater than the rest of your app */
    /* optional: */
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Comment: Try listening to the click event and prevent default. (click)="outsideClick($event)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a demo too as Mike said,

```
openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogResultExampleDialog,{disableClose:true});
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.selectedOption = result;
    });
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/4JNZcNACVeOW2NvsCrT8?p=preview)**

Answer (score 7):

You're using the Material Design dialog, which has an option to add a backdrop and prevent closing.

I think you need to do something like this:

```
this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogResultComponent, {
    disableClose: true,
    hasBackdrop: true // or false, depending on what you want
});
```

See the demo at https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/dialog/dialog-demo.ts.

Because the documentation is not yet ready, I've found it invaluable to look at their demo app, which is included in the source. You can run it locally with:

```
npm run demo-app
```

Comment: hey mike, i'm not sure it works. I added to my post what i did, can you see if that what you mean?

Comment: I added the HTML that you should add to your dialog template.

Comment: where did you add? I don't see

Comment: Take another look.

Comment: Ah ok - I've just noticed you are using the Material Design dialog. I changed my answer.

Comment: that's exactly what I need. thank you. do you know why   hasBackdrop: true isn't assignable to parameter of type 'mdDialogConfig'

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the `{}` around the config? If you copy and paste exactly what I wrote I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the parameter `disableClose:true` in the providers in your shared.module, for example. Then, all of your mat-dialog will be affected by this parameters:

```
providers: [{     
    provide: 
         MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, 
         useValue: { 
            disableClose: true,
            hasBackdrop: true 
          } 
    }
]
```